# How to serve custom MLflow model with Docker?

Tags: docker, mlflow

We have a project following essentially this
[docker example](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/tree/master/examples/docker) with the only difference that we created a custom model similar to [this](https://www.mlflow.org/docs/latest/models.html#custom-python-models) whose code lies in a directory called `forecast`. We succeeded in running the model with `mlflow run`. The problem arises when we try to serve the model. After doing

```
mlflow models build-docker -m "runs:/my-run-id/my-model" -n "my-image-name"
```

we fail running the container with

```
docker run -p 5001:8080 "my-image-name"
```

with the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'forecast'
```

It seems that the docker image is not aware of the source code defining our custom model class.
With Conda environnement the problem does not arise thanks to the `code_path` argument in `mlflow.pyfunc.log_model`.

Our Dockerfile is very basic, with just `FROM continuumio/miniconda3:4.7.12, RUN pip install {model_dependencies}`.

How to let the docker image know about the source code for deserialising the model and run it?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify source code dependencies by setting
*code_paths* argument when logging the model. So in your case, you can do something like:

```
mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(..., code_paths=[<path to your forecast.py file>])
```

Comment: I tried to add the path to my model.py but that's still giving the same error.

Comment: I just discovered that it does work if I put the entire directory in code_path: `code_path=os.path.join('forecast')`. 
However the predictions fail with a strange error starting with `{"error_code": "MALFORMED_REQUEST", "message": "Failed to parse input as a Pandas DataFrame. Ensure that the input is a valid JSON-formatted Pandas DataFrame with the split orient produced using the pandas.DataFrame.to_json(..., orient='split') method."`, but the json is actually in split orientation...

Comment: I forgot to mention, the same json used with `mlflow models serve`(Conda environment) works without problems

Comment: Hmm, code_path argument should be a list and it should work with both files and  directories. Can you share what error do you get if you set it as [<path-to-forecast.py]?

Comment: Can you share your mlflow version, conda env file for the model and part of your data that repros the problem? (the values and column names can be replaced)

Comment: MLflow 1.4, conda.yaml of the model is `channels:
- defaults - conda-forge
dependencies:
- python=3.7.4
- mlflow=1.4.0
- numpy=1.17.4
- scikit-learn=0.21.3
- cloudpickle=1.2.2`